# How to write a custom exception for Input stream that may end prematurely

Tags: java, inputstream, runtimeexception, custom-exceptions

I would like to write a custom exception **(RunTimeException**) for Input stream that may end prematurely instead of catching IOException for the following code:

```
    public static int deserializeInt(InputStream inputStream) {
    int deserializeObject;
    final int NUMBER_OF_BYTE_OF_INTEGER = 4;
    byte[] databytesArr = new byte[NUMBER_OF_BYTE_OF_INTEGER];
    try {
        inputStream.read(databytesArr, 0, databytesArr.length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    deserializeObject = ByteBuffer.wrap(databytesArr).getInt();
    return deserializeObject;
}
```

I would like a special class for the custom exception

Comment: and what exactly is the problem you are facing? just create a class that extends (Runtime)Exception

Comment: @Stultuske If I understand correctly, it is not about catching the IOE and throwing a custom one, but have the stream throw the custom one **instead** of the IOE. Which would make overriding `read` necessary maybe? Salem Masoud, can you clarify what you would lik to achieve? What do you want to do with the exception?